# Existe alguma ferramenta para encontrar respostas com links quebrados?

Tags: suporte, hyperlinks

Há pouco encontrei uma resposta minha com uma referência a uma página que não existe mais. Provavelmente existirão mais.

O Stack Overflow tem alguma ferramenta ou existe alguma forma para que eu possa encontrar, de forma fácil, respostas minhas com links quebrados?

Comment: Sei que existem coisas gerais, não para o SO.

Comment: @Maniero São possíveis de usar neste contexto?

Comment: Acho que sim, geralmente você coloca uma página base e ele vai caçando tudo (claro que poderá pegar coisas que não lhe interessam verificar. Acho que dá para *tunar*  um pouco.

Comment: Relacionada: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262038/221800 e https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300916/221800